# Stripe - Can a successful synchronous Charge later fail through a charge.failed event?

Tags: java, python, payment, stripe-payments

I am looking to integrate with Stripe and wanted to know if I need to take care of the following behavior:

1 - Successfully created a charge 
2 - At some later point in time could that charge be failed through the charge.failed webhook event?

Thanks